# How can I read 7z files directly from SAS?

Tags: sas, 7zip

I'm a SAS beginner programmer who has a lot of compressed files under 7z format. Because of lack of space in the server I work, I need to open files directly from their compressed form. I've found the following SAS documentation about Reading Compressed Text Files:

https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi31/155-31.pdf

However, I do not obtain any result using the next code, for example:

```
FileName Com7zipa Pipe '7za e "rie_mbco_matriz_07.7z" "rie_mbco_matriz_07.sas7bdat" -y -so';

Data DataSet07;
  infile Com7zipa;
  Input NRO_DOC;
run;
```

I hope you can help me.

Best regards,

Jean Pierre

Comment: First, what version of SAS do you have. Support for 7z is very new, as in 9.4M5 or M6 I think. You can check using `proc setinit;run;`.

Comment: Are you saying the 7z file contains a SAS dataset?  If so then just expand it into the WORK directory of your current SAS session and you can reference it as `WORK.rie_mbco_matriz_07`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, `gzip`is supported in 9.4M5 or above but `7z` is not. Although server space is limited, you will likely have at least a fair amount of SAS WORK directory space allocated. You can use `x` commands to unzip the file to the WORK directory instead and read it from there. Note that you will need to enable `x` commands first using this method.

Let's assume a file named `myfile.7z` has a csv file in it named `myfile.csv`.

```
/* Create a macro variable holding the location of the WORK directory */
%let workdir = %sysfunc(getoption(work));

x "7za e /my/dir/myfile.7z -o&workdir.";

proc import 
    file = "&workdir./myfile.csv"
    out  = myfile
    dbms = csv
    replace;
run;
```